# how insert value from ListString into Combobox selected Items and Textbox

Tags: c#, split, combobox, textbox, selecteditem

I have one list

```
1,XX000001,2,XX000002,3,XX000003,4,XX000004
```

I want to split and insert data using combobox selected items.
Like when I select 1 from combobox,  textbox.Text show DD000001 . If I select 2, textbox.Text show DD000002

Like now I split data like below, but I don't know how use combobox selected item to extract data into textbox.

```
if (lsdata[i].StartsWith("XX"))
{
  cbWorkOrder2.Items.Add(lsdata[i - 1]);
  //listBox1.Items.Add(lsdata[i]); //

}
```

Comment: To clarify, the combo box will contain options 1, 2, 3, 4 in this example and when the user makes a selection in the combo box the text box should be updated accordingly with the corresponding XX string?  Do you have control over the generation of the input string (list)?  The format does add some complexity that isn't unmanageable; however, if you're just trying to index the XX values and can change the input string list then that would remove some complexity.

Comment: yes. combobox contain option 1,2,3,4. when make selection like 1, textbox display XX000001 and 2 display XX000002 and so on. I dont have control the input list but format not change.